# MongoDB Compass won't connect to server, but command line works

Tags: mongodb, authentication, user-management

I'm running a local test environment with MongoDB on localhost. I can connect to it via Compass and command line using a root user.  However, I created another user on my working database (not the admin database).  I can connect using command line: `mongo localhost/[my db name] -u[my username]` but Compass times out (`mongodb://[my username]:[my password]@localhost/[my db name]`)

When connecting via command line, I can issue `use [my db name]` then `db.[collection name].find()` and I get the correct results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you resolve this?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: My problem is just opposite. I can connect through compass but command line is not working. It says _authentication error_.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Use `authSource=yourDBName` at the end of your connection string. Hence your connection string would be like:

```js
mongodb://[my username]:[my password]@localhost/[my db name]?authSource=[my db name]
```